# How to handle Unhandled exceptions in c# using TryParse

Tags: unhandled-exception, tryparse

```
if (response.ToLower() == "addition") 
{
Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
double addition = (num1) + (num2);
Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", addition);
if(!double.TryParse (num1, out addition))
     {
      Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
      tryAgain = true;   
     }
```

```
I tried to use try parse to handle my unhandled exception and make the user go back and do it again if they dont input a number/ integer/ decimal. I am new to try parse and dont know how to use it properly, So i would like to ask for a way in which i could handle exceptions in the future as well
```

Here's an inline link to replit(https://replit.com/@NitikPaudel/Maths-Calculator-Upgraded#main.cs)

Comment: What errors are you getting? Can you explain what you are trying to do with TryParse, seems like Try/Catch would work better. Or a TryParse higher up instead of the double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());  Also, believe TryParse needs a string, not a double, as the first param unless you are using a non-standard library.

Comment: cannot convert from double to system.ReadOnlySpan<char>

Comment: i still dont know how to fix it using a string

Comment: I am new to try parse and one of my friends told me it is the best way to deal with unhandled exceptions

Comment: How can i use Try/Catch because that is another suggestion i got as well?

Answer (score 0):

I'd try something like below:

```
    if (response.ToLower() == "addition") 
    {
    double num1;
    double num2;
    Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
    if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToString(),num1)){
       Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
          tryAgain = true;
    };

    Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
    if(!double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToString(),num2)){
       Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
          tryAgain = true;
    };

    double addition = (num1) + (num2);
    Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", addition);
}
```

Or if you would prefer a try/catch

```
if (response.ToLower() == "addition") 
{
    try{
        Console.Write("Enter a number: ");
        double num1 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Enter another number: ");
        double num2 = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double addition = (num1) + (num2);
        Console.WriteLine("The answer is {0}", addition);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        Console.WriteLine("Try Again");
        tryAgain = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the Exception e has the error if you want to log that or write it.

Answer (score 0):

The function `TryParse` is here to check if a value can be converted and to prevent the exception before it is thrown.

To handle exceptions, you can use `try catch`, example:

```
try {
    // do the work
}
catch (Exception ex) {
    // work with exception
}
```

View this documentation: https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-exception-handling